# Using archive file for compiled object seems to break compilation

Tags: c++, c, gcc5

I have a large project with a custom Makefile building everything. This is for an ARM Cortex-M0.

One of the steps is to compile a Newlib `syscalls.c` into `syscalls.c.o`. That gets dumped into an archive file `newlib.a` which in turn is linked to the final `output.elf` for loading onto my device's flash.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -o output.elf .bld/*.c.o .bld/*.cpp.o .bld/libs/*.a -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Tlinker.ld -Wl,-Map=output.map --specs=nano.specs
```

If I follow the above procedure, sometimes the "Archive has no index":

```
.bld/libs/newlib.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
```

And sometimes (I have not figured out how to deterministically make one or the other happen) I get an undefined reference even though `_init()` is defined, as an empty function, in `syscalls.c`.

```
c:/progra~2/gnutoo~1/50a5a~1.420/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m\libc_nano.a(lib_a-init.o): In function `__libc_init_array':
init.c:(.text.__libc_init_array+0x1c): undefined reference to `_init'
```

However, if I skip the `newlib.a` file and just directly link `syscalls.c.o` into the final `.elf`, it works as expected.

What about using an archive could be causing this issue? I've also tried reordering the arguments to the linker to no avail.

#### Note (edit)

I did notice the `run ranlib to add one` instruction. However, this does not apply because:

1. This is not necessary on other archives that I'm building, why is it needed here?
2. That error doesn't happen anymore (after some fiddling. not sure what changed). The main issue is that `_init` is undefined.

---

#### Reference

1. I'm compiling other archive files in this build with no issues. The unique things here are that this archive only has one file in it and it's the only C-only archive. However, I don't see how this could affect things.
2. This is basically how I'm compiling `syscalls.c` and archiving the `.o` file:

   ```
   $ arm-none-eabi-gcc newlib/syscalls.c -o .bld/newlib/syscalls.c.o -c -std=gnu11 -Wstrict-prototypes -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -O2 -pipe -ffreestanding -funsigned-bitfields -Wall -Wfatal-errors -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -MP -MF .bld/.dep/newlib/syscalls.c.o.d
   $ arm-none-eabi-ar rcs .bld/libs/newlib.a .bld/newlib/syscalls.c.o
   ```
3. `gcc` version

   ```
   arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.4.1 20160919 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 240496]
   ```
4. Simplified `syscalls.c`

   ```
   caddr_t _sbrk(int nbytes) __attribute__((externally_visible));
   void _init(void) __attribute__((externally_visible));

   /* c++ destructor dynamic shared object needed if -fuse-cxa-atexit is used*/
   void *__dso_handle __attribute__ ((weak));

   // defined in linker script
   extern caddr_t Heap_Bank1_Start;
   extern caddr_t Heap_Bank1_End;

   caddr_t _sbrk(int nbytes) { /* ... */ }
   void _init(void) {}
   ```

Comment: Did you run `ranlib`?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Is probably right, and the error message "Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one" gives it away. You need to run ranlib

Comment: It means the archive has no index; you can run ranlib to add one.

Comment: Why would I need to run `ranlib` on this archive and not any others?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this hint can help you: https://github.com/ap4y/modbus.js/issues/1

> Hi, you have this error because static library (libmodbus.a) have been
>   precompiled for other platform. Actually, it my mistake to leave it in
>   repository. In order to resolve this error you should compile library
>   for your platform and replace it in lib directory.